# Using the Offset Function with dynamic Row number

Tags: vba, excel-2007

Looking for a way to make this code work:

the idea is to paste the block of data dynamically underneath the last used cell of the sheet

Specifically I am lookimng for a way to do this dynamically using the offset function

```
Dim Sit As Long
Set Sit = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

data_sheet1.Range(data_sheet1.Cells(1, iCol), data_sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy Destination:=target_Sheet.Cells(1, TargetCol).Offset(Sit, 0)
```

many thanks

---

```
Sub test()

Dim Sit As Long
Sit = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox (Sit)

End Sub
```

this is were the error lies; I have isolated this bit of code

Comment: Remove the word `Set` in `Set Sit = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` By the way your code can fail under several instances, It is much better to fully qualify objects and then use them...

Comment: and also: target_Sheet.Cells(Sit, TargetCol).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: OK it keeps telling an Object is required:(

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490.aspx)

> **Set Keyword:**   In VBA, the Set keyword
>   is necessary to distinguish between
>   assignment of an object and assignment
>   of the default property of the object.
>   Since default properties are not
>   supported in Visual Basic .NET, the
>   Set keyword is not needed and is no
>   longer supported.

See this example

```
Dim Sit As Long
With target_Sheet
    Sit = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

With data_sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy _
    target_Sheet.Cells(Sit, TargetCol)
End With
```